# Discord.js Reaction Collector is buggy

Tags: discord.js

So, I've managed to make my reaction collector work. However, it doesn't actually do anything when I react on a reaction. I added a console.log function inside of my `collector.on` section, which DOES work, but the `switch` in it does not. Here's the code.

```
            console.log(`User Report Created (reportCreated = true)`);

            try {
                await newUserEmbed.react("");
                await newUserEmbed.react("❌");
                await newUserEmbed.react("❓");
            } catch (err) {
              message.channel.send('`ERROR: Reactions Error`');
              throw err;
            };

            const collector = newUserEmbed.createReactionCollector(
              (reaction, user) => message.guild.members.cache.find((member) => member.id === user.id).hasPermission("MANAGE_CHANNELS"),
              { dispose: true }
            );

            collector.on('collect', (message, reaction, user) => {
                console.log('Collecting Reactions for User Report (collectorRun = true)');
                switch (reaction.emoji){
                    case "":
                      newUserEmbed.delete();
                      message.reply(`This report for ${args[1]} has been marked as completed.`);
                      break;
                    case "❌":
                      newUserEmbed.delete();
                      message.reply(`This report for ${args[1]} has been declined.`);
                      break;
                    case "❓":
                      newUserEmbed.delete();
                      message.reply(`This report for ${args[1]} has been marked as inconclusive.`);
                      break;
                }
            });
```

Comment: What do you see in the console when you log `reaction.emoji`.

Comment: It's just the ```console.log``` function I placed inside of ```collector.on```, which is

```console.log('Collecting Reactions for User Report (collectorRun = true)');``` There's no errors, the ```switch``` is just.... completely silent.

Answer (score 0):

change `reaction.emoji` to `reaction.emoji.name` ?
if it does not working
plz type it `console.log(reaction.emoji)`
and tell me the result.

Comment: This causes the console to respond with "TypeErr: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'message' parameter in collect event. See: [discord.js Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/ReactionCollector?scrollTo=e-collect)[image: discord.js Documentation]

```js
collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
    console.log('Collecting Reactions for User Report (collectorRun = true)');
    switch (reaction.emoji){
        case "":
          newUserEmbed.delete();
          message.reply(`This report for ${args[1]} has been marked as completed.`);
          break;
        case "❌":
          newUserEmbed.delete();
          message.reply(`This report for ${args[1]} has been declined.`);
          break;
        case "❓":
          newUserEmbed.delete();
          message.reply(`This report for ${args[1]} has been marked as inconclusive.`);
          break;
        default:
          break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Show an example that helps achieve the question's goal